# 2009 impala cranks but won't start

Tags: chevrolet, cranks-wont-run, impala

Was driving on the interstate the other day with the cruise control on when it seemed like the car started losing power.  I pulled it over to the side of the interstate and it died.  I was able to crank it, but it wouldn't catch and start.  Had the battery replaced as the old one was about 5 years old.  Car started right up, however died again after about 5 minutes.  Now I can just get it to crank, but it won't catch.  Occasionally it will seem to start for about 1/2 a second and die again.  When I turn the key to the on position I can hear the fuel pump being primed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Whether you can hear the fuel pump or not, check the fuel pressure at the fuel injector rail (with a gauge) to ensure you have pressure.

Comment: Are you seeing any codes? Might want to hook up a code reader.

Comment: What’s the engine?

Comment: Suspect a failing fuel pump. Any codes in the computer?

Comment: I used my OBDII reader and it didn't pick up any codes.  It is a 3.9L V6 for the engine.   I bought a fuel pressure system tester today.  Removed the Gas cap, disconnected the fuel pump fuse, and tried to start the car.  It didn't start.  According to the manual I had that should have released the fuel pressure.  I then then connected the fuel pressure tester to the pressure valve on the fuel rail.  Put the fuel pump fuse back in and tried to start the car.  It actually started for about 10 seconds, but then died.

Comment: I tried to get it to start multiple times after that, but it never ran for more than a half a second. During all this time the pressure tester never read anything for pressure.  Is that even more indicative of a failing fuel pump?